# NodeJS emit event is not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this `NodeJS` code, and I have no idea why the `emit` function is not firing, It only fires when I put it inside a callback function like `setTimeout`

```
 const url = require('url');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const events = require('events');

WebSocketServer = new events.EventEmitter();

WebSocketServer.start =  (server) => {
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({server});
    console.log('websocket started');
    WebSocketServer.emit('started');
};

module.exports = WebSocketServer;
```

Here I test if emitted:

```
const ExpressServer = require('./server/api/expressServer');
const WebsocketServer = require('./server/websocket/websocketServer');

WebsocketServer.start(ExpressServer.server);

WebsocketServer.on('started', () => {
    console.log('web socket emitted');
    ExpressServer.start();
});
```

Comment: try `this.emit('started')`

Comment: `this.emit is not a function`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219382/node-js-event-emitter-not-working-if-we-first-emit-and-then-we-listen/44220594

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the order, first listen to events and then fire fuctions:

```
const ExpressServer = require('./server/api/expressServer');
const WebsocketServer = require('./server/websocket/websocketServer');

WebsocketServer.on('started', () => {
    console.log('web socket emitted');
    ExpressServer.start();
});

WebsocketServer.start(ExpressServer.server);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not using EventEmitter and Websocket the right away. Below is a working example of both combined:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter(); //You didnt call EventEmitter() in your code
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket(//Your path here);

ws.on('open', function open() {
  console.log('websocket started');
  EventEmitter.emit('started');
});
```

Comment: I know that it will work like that, but my question was why I can`t emit after my own function.

Comment: You would need to write this: `const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter();` but you wrote this: `const EventEmitter = require('events');`

Comment: `const events = require('events');

WebSocketServer = new events.EventEmitter();` not working

Comment: try to use exactly this `require('events').EventEmitter()`